# Do I have to create a facebook app to use the SDK?

Tags: facebook

Am working to create a tool on windows desktop that will pull out the facebook feed/wall. I went through the SDK's available and it seems like to setup a facebook application it is required. Please advice if there is other approached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, do it in the developer app in facebook. It's not a big deal and it doesn't get exposed to other users unless you submit it to the marketplace. Basically you just need to get your api keys from it.